# Does Amazon charge if VM machine is running and there are not activities

Tags: amazon-ec2

This question is not very complicated. I want to use an Amazon EC2 virtual machine. In most cases, this machine will only have idle activities i.e. doing nothing. How will Amazon charge money in that case? Because on one hand it is running, but on the other hand it doesn't use CPU.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2549035/do-you-get-charged-for-a-stopped-instance-on-ec2?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are charged for every hour the instance is in a "running" state. It doesn't matter how busy the CPU is.

However, you probably won't incur any I/O or bandwidth costs while nothing is happening.