# If elastic ip is associated with a stopped ec2 instance, is there charge?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, elastic-ip

The question came from this question: [Do you get charged for a 'stopped' instance on EC2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2549035/do-you-get-charged-for-a-stopped-instance-on-ec2)

Elastic IPs are heavily charged when not in use, according to the Amazon docs. Does that count (are you going to get charged for not using the elastic IP) if you associate elastic IPs to a stopped ec2 VM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html) (emphasis mine):

> To ensure efficient use of Elastic IP addresses, we impose a small
>   hourly charge if an Elastic IP address is not associated with a
>   running instance, **or if it is associated with a stopped instance** or an
>   unattached network interface.

So you can't avoid the charge by associating it with a stopped instance.